# Запросы к бд выполняются без ошибок, но не изменяют ее

Tags: java, mysql

Есть класс для работы с базой данных MySQL. Все методы раньше в нем работали, но перестали после выполнения такого запроса.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Но при попытке изменить значение обратно на 1, оно сохраняется только на период сессии. Ниже описание класса и один из методов.

```
public class DatabaseWork {
// подключение к бд
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/players?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
private static final String user = "user";
private static final String password = "password";

// переменные подключения
private static Connection con = null;
private static Statement stmt = null;
private static ResultSet rs = null;

// строка запроса
private String query;

public void banIp(String ipaddress, String reason) {
    query = "INSERT INTO `bannedip` (`ip`, `reason`) VALUES ('" + ipaddress + "', '" + reason + "');";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        // getting Statement object to execute query
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace(); }
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Этот же запрос прекрасно работает в самой СУБД. И в программе он выполняется без исключений, но данные в бд не отображаются (не вставляются?).

Вот так я создаю объект класса и вызываю метод.

```
DatabaseWork db = new DatabaseWork();
db.banIp("hjg996k", "reason");
```

Однако при попытке вставить те же данные  (первое поле имеет уникальный индекс) происходит ошибка:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'hjg996k' for key 2
```

Всегда для ключа 2.

Я теряюсь в догадках, что могло пойти не так. Ведь утром это работало.

**UPDATE**

Но когда я делаю выборку из таблицы:

```
query = "select * from bannedip";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
}
```

То все записи выводятся без проблем (но их нет в базе, если делать выборку через cmd). Хотя перед этим я удалил все записи из таблицы в MySQL через cmd.

Может ли моя бд жить отдельной жизнью в Java-программе?

Comment: Транзакцию у `statement` комитить нужно?

Comment: Посмотрите, что у Вас с автокоммитом транзакций. Если автокоммита нет, значит нужно после отработки запроса делать коммит руками.

Comment: Автокоммит включен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за внимание!

Причиной проблемы стала невнимательность. После выполнения этого запроса все стало понятно:

```
SELECT @@datadir;
```

Программа использовала директорию прошлого сервера. После его удаления все заработало как прежде.

Однако, почему программа начала использовать его только вчера, а не раньше...